# css animation spin - how to make 2 elements spin together in unison?

Tags: css

I got 2 divs .. div1 and div2. They start spinning on click. They may be clicked at any time. When I click div1 it starts spinning and when I click div2 it starts spinning - great.

The problem is, regardless of when they are clicked, I want them to spin together - that is, I want them to both be rotated at the same angle all the time whilst they are spinning.

So for example, if div1 is at 45deg when div2 is clicked - div2 should jump to a 45deg rotation and start spinning.

Is there any way to do this in CSS only or does this require JS?

The current spin CSS:

```
&.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%,#ffffff 100%);
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

The active class is applied to a div onClick (using the Angular framework).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rotation "jump" you're looking for won't look exactly great. However, answering your main question: **no, you can't get that information in CSS**.

I see two solutions:

- Since you're going to make a rotation without animation before the spin starts, you could always restart the first div rotation and start it again, so both will be synched.
- If you really want the second div to be synched with the first one, good news are that you're already using Angular so you can calculate the rotation angle of div1, apply it to div2 and start spinning.